# Google Drive File Upload Daemon

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I want a python scripts which uploads files to google drive periodically in the background.
I have created a separate google drive account for this purpose. The file should be uploaded to this account, not the user's personal account. The script should upload files to this folder without asking the user to login to his google account. How can I achieve this, as all samples that I see open up the login page in the browser?

As of now, I am using this code :
https://gist.github.com/macieksk/038b201a54d9e804d1b5

Comment: The wizard at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/wizard tells me you need a _service account_ for this. Service accounts are added in your Google Cloud project.

Comment: Hi! You can use json credentials as specified by the Google API - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python